# how to add loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

Could someone help me add a loop to my program?

Here's the code:

```
cout << "What do you do?" "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "(Press Enter...)";
    cin.ignore();
       cout << "\n";
        cout << "Stay in bed?" "\n";
        cout << "Go to the bathroom?" "\n";
        cout << "Go downstairs?" "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    string answer;
    getline(cin, answer);

        if (answer == "stay in bed", "Stay in bed")
            {
                cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
            }

        else if (answer == "go to the bathroom", "Go to the bathroom")
            {
                cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom";
            }
        else if (answer == "go downstairs", "Go downstairs")
            {
                cout << "You get up and walk downstairs to the kitchen.";
            }
        else
            {
                cout << "That is not a valid answer...";
            }
           cin.ignore();
```

How should I add a loop to where when user enters something falling under the condition of "else", the loop returns to ask "What do you do?"

Comment: `if (answer == "stay in bed", "Stay in bed")`  Explain what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Ahh yes, the reason there are two options is because I want the user to get the same output regardless of whether they capitalize the input. I know there a more efficient way to do that but that's what I got for now.

Comment: That line of code and similar lines do not do what you think they do.   Where have you seen an `if` statements that looks anything like what you posted?  Correction: `if (answer == "whatever" || answer == "Whatever")`

Comment: Like I said Im new to this, this is the first code ive written so please pardon the errors. But I appreciate the correction :)

Comment: So your content with using a construct without knowing what it **really** was doing?  You'e using the `comma operator`, and it did *not* compare your `answer` variable with 2 strings.

Comment: What happens if you try that code with some *other* string? You tested it with those two strings, but in fact it'll match anything. It's good that you know to test things (you'd be amazed how many professionals don't know that), but you must test things in both directions.

Comment: Haha yes, I see how I messed up and I fixed the problem using PaulMcKenzie's correction.

Comment: @Username_000 So to your question, when is the loop supposed to quit?  All your options do not give a way out if the user wants to exit.

Comment: Well I don't know how or where to add the loop, but I want the loop to execute only if the user enters a value resulting in the "else" if statement. So if you enter something and you get out "That is not a valid answer" then you get the question again "What do you do?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way to do what you want to do (or what I *think* you want to do). One way is to put the whole thing inside an endless loop and use `break` to get out:

```
while(1)
{
  cout << "What do you do?\n";
  getline(cin, answer);

  if (answer == "stay in bed")
  {
    cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
    break;
  }
  else if (answer == "go to the bathroom")
  {
    cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I followed your model and it worked exactly as I wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool repeatInput = false;
do
{
  cout << "What do you do?" "\n";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "(Press Enter...)";
  cin.ignore();
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "Stay in bed?" "\n";
  cout << "Go to the bathroom?" "\n";
  cout << "Go downstairs?" "\n";
  cout << "\n";
  repeatInput = false;
  getline(cin, answer);

  if (answer == "stay in bed" || answer == "Stay in bed")
  {
    cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
  }
  else if (answer == "go to the bathroom" || answer == "Go to the bathroom")
  {
    cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom";
  }
  else if (answer == "go downstairs" || answer == "Go downstairs")
  {
    cout << "You get up and walk downstairs to the kitchen.";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "That is not a valid answer...";
    repeatInput = true;
  }
  cin.ignore();
}while(repeatInput == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

using `while` you can add a loop in your program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
while (true) {
cout << "What do you do?" "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "(Press Enter...)";

cout << "\n";
cout << "Stay in bed?" "\n";
cout << "Go to the bathroom?" "\n";
cout << "Go downstairs?" "\n";
cout << "\n";

string answer;
getline(cin, answer);

    if (answer == "stay in bed", "Stay in bed")
        {
            cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent." << endl;
        }

    else if (answer == "go to the bathroom", "Go to the bathroom")
        {
            cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom" << endl;
        }
    else if (answer == "go downstairs", "Go downstairs")
        {
            cout << "You get up and walk downstairs to the kitchen." << endl;
        }
    else
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid answer..." << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;

}

return 0;

}
```

this code `while(true)` if the condition is `true` or `1` the code inside the brackets will execute and if the condition is `false` or `0` the code will exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

this answer spare of putting break in every else-if function. I used "continue" in hope you will explore c++ language and learn more!

```
bool check_if_true=true;
while(check_if_true){
    cout << "What do you do?" "\n";
            cout << "\n";
            cout << "(Press Enter...)";
            cin.ignore();
               cout << "\n";
                cout << "Stay in bed?" "\n";
                cout << "Go to the bathroom?" "\n";
                cout << "Go downstairs?" "\n";
            cout << "\n";

            string answer;
            getline(cin, answer);

                if (answer == "stay in bed", "Stay in bed")
                    {
                        cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent.";
                    }

                else if (answer == "go to the bathroom", "Go to the bathroom")
                    {
                        cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom";
                    }
                else if (answer == "go downstairs", "Go downstairs")
                    {
                        cout << "You get up and walk downstairs to the kitchen.";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        cout << "That is not a valid answer...";
                        continue;//return to the start of the while loop
                    }
                   cin.ignore();
              check_if_true=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use integer identifiers when giving a user options.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int id;
    cout << "What do you wanna do?\n" << endl;
    cout << "(0) Quit program" << endl;
    cout << "(1) Stay in bed" << endl;
    cout << "(2) Go to the bathroom" << endl;
    cout << "(3) Go downstairs\n" << endl;

    while (id != 0)
    {
        cout << "Choose your option: ";
        cin >> id;

        switch (id)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "You lay there, motionless. Silent." << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "You get up and walk across the hall to the bathroom." << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "You get up and walk downstairs to the kitchen." << endl;
            break;

        case 0:
            cout << "Exitting application!" << endl;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Error: Invalid option!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code is a lot cleaner and easily extensible. You should never have a user input strings when denoting options. The only exception is if you have an underlying program that scans the sentences and derives a course of action from 'keywords' found in the sentence. This is more algorithmic intensive and probably not what you're after, and assuming you are new to C++ I relate to my code in showing that this is the solution that's more practical in your situation. The code was tested, and runs fine.